# Disappearing instance of an object in Rails View

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created a public method in a "List" model that will find a substitute "Item" given the items id. I've hard-coded the id in the sample (the behavior is the same with a variable).

Here is the List model:

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  def substitute_item
    Item.find(1)
  end
end
```

I access the method inside a partial that is rendered by the List's show view, when I inspect the method, I get the object that I want, then if I try to access the name of the object, it fails.

Inside the partial, with a working call to "inspect":

```
<%= list.substitute_item.inspect %>
```

Output from successful call to inspect:

```
#<Item id: 1, name: "Item 1", created_at: "2014-05-20 18:20:20", updated_at: "2014-05-20 18:20:20">
```

Inside the partial with a broken call to the item's name:

```
<%= list.substitute_item.name %>
```

Getting a NilClass error:

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

What am I missing here? Is there a different way to call the find method that will create a usable instance of the Item object that I want? I would like to keep this method in the model, but if it will only work in the controller, I could move it.

I have tried using an instance variable in the view (partial), same results:

```
# Successful call to inspect
<% @substitute = list.substitute_item %>
<%= @substitute.inspect %>

# Failed call to name
<% @substitute = list.substitute_item %>
<%= @substitute.name %>
```

Comment: So could this question be simplified to a console example? Say... `Item.find(1).inspect` works but `Item.find(1).name` does not? Or does it work in the console? If so then do you have the `name` method defined / doing custom things?

Comment: Everything works in the console, I can't reproduce the problem there. I don't have anything custom for the name in either of the models, but they both have a name field. If the problem was strictly with the models, I would think it would also break in the console, as I think you were implying.

Comment: Can you post more of the exception trace? We have little go on. Also, have you tried inserting a debugger in the view and probing the object to try to learn more that way?

Comment: list is not an ivar (unlike `@substitute`) how are you passing that thing around? any chance you are doing the `render` call with the wrong parameters?

Comment: @phoet Good question. `list` is the variable I get from the collection I send to "render partial." I can access other parts of that var with no problem, (e.g. the name of the primary item). As mentioned in Rich Peck's answer, I think the issue here is trying to chain one model to another without creating an association, which does not work.

Answer (score 1):

> So could this question be simplified to a console example? Say...
>   Item.find(1).inspect works but Item.find(1).name does not?

Won't reproduce the result because it's a different setup

The problem is the code is trying to call an `ActiveRecord` object through an `instance method`. The method will be self-contained (how do you call a chained command on a method which will not support it?)

I don't know if what I'm saying is correct (I'll have to research how to create AR objects etc), but you should try this:

```
def substitute_item
    Item.find(1).name
end
```

This will return *only* the `name` attribute for the `Item.find(1)` query, which should allow you to output it in your view (with `item.list_substitute`). If this works, I believe my hypothesis will have substance; if not, it's back to the drawing board :)

---

**Class Objects**

I don't know the correct terminology for this, but I hope it gives you some ideas:

--

**Instance Method**

You're calling an [instance method](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/) on an object to load another object. I get you're trying to use the instance method as a way to populate the object, but this will only populate that method with the object; meaning any use of `.name` etc will not work

--

**Object**

After reading some of the [Ruby docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html), you'll be able to see that it's Object-Orientated. I believe your answer is to find out how to chain an object onto another object

I can read up on how to do this if you wish. I will ask some Ruby people on how to do it, too

--

**Fix**

Maybe going into a chat session will help us get a workable solution?

Comment: This does work for outputting the name to the view. I was hoping to get the whole object because there are more fields in there that I want. At the moment, only two, so I can write methods for each one. I was just trying to avoid multiple trips to the database every time there is a substitute item. Perhaps I should move the method to a helper or put the call to `Item.find(id)` directly in the view?

Comment: Putting `Item.find(id)` directly in the view works. I was under the impression that it is bad practice to use ActiveRecord class methods directly in views. Should it never be done, only in special cases, or is it not a problem at all? Still new to Rails, coming from a SQL Server background.

Comment: Hi there! Sorry about the late reply! Let me have a look at this for you :)

Comment: `ActiveRecord` calls in the view - **don't do it**. Rails has `controllers`, `helpers` & `models` for a reason - so you can build your data objects in places other than the view. I would highly recommend keeping your data-assignment in the `controller` (conforming with [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) principles)

Comment: Rich, thank you. As far as chaining on ActiveRecord models goes, rails associations (has_many, belongs_to, has_many through, etc.) are the only wya I know. Originally, I was working on that setup but after a few hours, I could not get rails to use the fields that I wanted for the foreign key relationship - I kept getting the incorrect substitute item. Using the direct call to "where" got be the correct record right away. Setting up the correct association is worth a separate question, and when I don't have a deadline looming I will craft that question...for right now, I'll use a helper.

Comment: Rich, I am satisfied for my project having this method in a helper. For my own curiosity and for anyone who references this question, when assigning an instance variable in the method, it still doesn't work. Is this because the instance variable is just a reference to the method without instantiating an actual object?